# Creating MySQL Spatial Procedure in MySQL 5.0

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, geospatial, spatial, procedure

I found a procedure that pretty much meets exactly what I am looking for here on this page:

http://www.scribd.com/doc/2569355/Geo-Distance-Search-with-MySQL

I have modified it just a little to actually work with my database, but everytime i go to create the function it throws an error. I am under the assumption that I can't actually create a precedure in MySQL 5.0 but rather I have to create a function. I just need a little help. I am very new to creating procedures for MySQL.

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `GEODIST` $$
CREATE FUNCTION `GEODIST`( mylat float, mylong float, dist int )
BEGIN
    DECLARE lon1 float; 
    DECLARE lon2 float;
    DECLARE lat1 float; 
    DECLARE lat2 float;

set lon1 = mylon - dist/abs(cos(radians(mylat))*69);
set lon2 = mylon + dist/abs(cos(radians(mylat))*69);
set lat1 = mylat - (dist/69);
set lat2 = mylat + (dist/69);

SELECT destination.*,3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN((orig.lat -dest.lat) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) +COS(orig.lat * pi()/180) * COS(dest.lat * pi()/180) *POWER(SIN((orig.lon -dest.lon) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) )) as distance FROM users destination, users origin WHERE origin.id=userid
and destination.longitude between lon1 and lon2 and destination.latitude between lat1 and lat2 
having distance < dist ORDER BY Distance limit 10;

END $$
```

When I run this code an error is thrown:

> Error SQL query: Documentation
>
> CREATE FUNCTION `GEODIST` (
>
> mylat FLOAT, mylong FLOAT, dist INT ) BEGIN DECLARE lon1 FLOAT;
>
> DECLARE lon2 FLOAT;
>
> DECLARE lat1 FLOAT;
>
> DECLARE lat2 FLOAT;
>
> SET lon1 = mylon - dist / ABS( COS( RADIANS( mylat ) ) *69 ) ;
>
> SET lon2 = mylon + dist / ABS( COS( RADIANS( mylat ) ) *69 ) ;
>
> SET lat1 = mylat - ( dist /69 ) ;
>
> SET lat2 = mylat + ( dist /69 ) ;
>
> SELECT destination . * , 3956 *2 * ASIN( SQRT( POWER( SIN( ( orig.lat
>   - dest.lat ) * PI( ) /180 /2 ) , 2 ) + COS( orig.lat * PI( ) /180 ) * COS( dest.lat * PI( ) /180 ) * POWER( SIN( ( orig.lon - dest.lon ) *
>   PI( ) /180 /2 ) , 2 ) ) ) AS distance FROM users destination, users
>   origin WHERE origin.id = userid AND destination.longitude BETWEEN lon1
>   AND lon2 AND destination.latitude BETWEEN lat1 AND lat2 HAVING
>   distance < dist ORDER BY Distance LIMIT 10 ;
>
> END $$ MySQL said: Documentation
>
> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>
> near 'BEGIN
>       DECLARE lon1 float; 
>       DECLARE lon2 float;
>       DECLARE lat1 float' at line 2

EDIT: I was advised below to change this to a PROCEDURE in which I have, but it is throwing the error:

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>
> near '' at line 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not need to return a value from stored routine, then you need to create a procedure, just change `CREATE FUNCTION` to `CREATE PROCEDURE`.

Othervise it is needed to add `RETURNS` clause to specify result data type, and `RETURN` clause in the function's body to set result value.

[CREATE PROCEDURE and CREATE FUNCTION Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-procedure.html).

Comment: Thank you, I just got that. I did change it, but it is still throwing the same error for me.

Comment: Sorry, now I am getting a different error. I just updated the question. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Nevermind, I got that up and running. Awesome! Thanks for your help!